# Android .apk app install success but in my android emulator have not contain this application

Tags: c++, android-ndk, sdl-2

```
[2015-02-05 19:20:51 - dsadas] Android Launch!    
[2015-02-05 19:20:52 - dsadas] adb is running normally.    
[2015-02-05 19:20:53 - dsadas] No Launcher activity found!    
[2015-02-05 19:20:54 - dsadas] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!    
[2015-02-05 19:20:55 - dsadas] Performing sync    Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...    
[2015-02-05 19:21:40 - dsadas] Uploading MyFirstGame.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'    
[2015-02-05 19:22:10 - dsadas] Installing MyFirstGame.apk...    
[2015-02-05 19:22:30 - dsadas] Success!    
[2015-02-05 19:22:35 - dsadas] \MyFirstGame\bin\MyFirstGame.apk installed on device    
[2015-02-05 19:22:37 - dsadas] Done!
```

My Project is write on SDL and C++,and I use NDK for eclipse. I don't have an errors and when start apk file on my phone it was installing success but there is not a game on the screen and Open Button is disable..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.libsdl.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:hasCode="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"         android:name="org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intend.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="android.app.lib_MyFirstGame"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Probably an error in the manifest.  Can you post it here please.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that your activity class is not actually called org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity

Comment: Were can I found the right android::name of that activity class?